# Using Koolplot without creating a new window for graphing

Tags: c++, winapi, graph, plot

I have been experimenting with the Koolplot plotting library. I have managed to set up the linking and includes so everything compiles nicely. I was wondering if it was possible to plot a graph within a current window. Whenever `plot(x, y);` is called, it creates a new pop-up window with the graph in it. I would like to have this graph be integrated into the current window instead of opening a new window just for the graph. For example I have a simple Win32 window and I would like the graph to be displayed on it.

I am using C++ Win32 API (not MFC or VC++) on Windows 7 with GNU Compiler. If there are any other graphing libraries that are better than Koolplot and that have an API that can be used, let me know. (I don't want a binary like gnuplot.exe that has to be called from my program.)